# Accessing TeamCity using Authenticationn/Access Token gives error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: powershell, teamcity

Trying to access TeamCity using the Authentication (feature which was added recently by JetBrains into TeamCity). The documentation is very poor with no example. It just doesn't work for me.

**EXECUTING POWERSHELL COMMAND**

Following is not the only way I tried, but as an example posting the command invoking a rest method like:

```
$body="<build branchName=`"development`" rebuildAllDependencies=`"true`"><buildType id=`"DevSandbox_TestArea_PageAutomation`"/></build>"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://teamcity.my.domain.com/httpAuth/app/rest/buildQueue/ -Method Post -ContentType application/xml -Body $body -Headers @{Origin= 'http://teamcity.my.domain.com'; Authorization= 'Bearer tEamCitYauThtoKen'} -UseBasicParsing
```

**ERROR**

Getting the following error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://teamcity.my.domain.com/httpAuth/app/r ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Could anyone please help me what's wrong with the headers and/or anything that is missing?

**FURTHER REFERENCE:**

[TeamCity 2019.1 Help - Managing Access Token](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2019.1/managing-your-user-account.html#Managing-Access-Tokens)

[Powershell 6 - Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Have you ever tried with postman ?

Comment: @NirajGajjar Yes it's working with postman

Comment: @NirajGajjar ... In the 'Authorization' tab, I added the token... In the 'Headers' tab, I added Origin and Conten-Type keys and their values and in the 'Body' tab, the Xml part. I then used the POST method to post the URL: http://teamcity.my.domain.com/httpAuth/app/rest/buildQueue/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `/httpAuth/` part in the url is only required when accessing the TeamCity server using Basic Authentication.

So the solution is to use the url `http://teamcity.my.domain.com/app/rest/buildQueue/`
instead of `http://teamcity.my.domain.com/httpAuth/app/rest/buildQueue/`
since you use Token-Based Authentication.